# Serve index.html without a redirect on 404 keeping url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using an SPA and my local dev environment serves the index.html file for any 404s. This keeps the URL intact when loading the app. My apps routing picks up the URL and displays the correct page.

I currently have 404 redirects in s3 to index.html

Current behavior

- Navigate to www.example.com/clients
- s3 detects 404
- redirect to www.example.com/index.html
- SPA sees the endpoint is /index.html and cannot find page

Desired behavior

- Navigate to www.example.com/clients
- detect 404
- Serve index.html no redirect
- SPA sees the endpoint is /clients and displays clients page

I'm hoping I can achieve this without needing to run a server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure `index.html` for both Index Document and Error document with no redirects configured, then:

- Request for `www.example.com` shows `www.example.com/index.html` with 200 status code, client sees `www.example.com`.
- Request for `www.example.com/sub1` (found) shows `www.example.com/sub1/index.html` with 200 status code, client sees `www.example.com/sub1` with no redirect.
- Request for `www.example.com/sub1` (not found) shows `www.example.com/index.html` with 404 status code, client sees `www.example.com/sub1` with no redirect.

There is no way to change this behaviour. If you want it different, then you'll need to use your own server.

Comment: I don't get this behavior. I get: Request for www.example.com shows www.example.com/index.html with 200 status code, client sees www.example.com/index.html.

Comment: Do you have any redirection rules attached to your bucket?

Comment: Yes I do. Perhaps I need to remove these?

Comment: It's highly likely they are affecting the behaviour of the bucket. You may need to change them.

Comment: Wow thankyou! Removing the redirects works. I didn't know this behaviour was default